# Correct Architecture for Monolith with Go

Tags: rest, clean-code, go, clean-architecture

I'm designing a monolith RESTful API that potentially sometime in the future may turn into microservices. I'm also trying following Uncle Bob's clean code as well. My question lies in structuring the Go code. Many times I see the following file structure for example:

```
|-- users
| --/  driver
| --/  entity
| --/  usescases
| --/  controller
|-- posts
| --/  driver
| --/  entity
| --/  usescases
| --/  controller
```

And the respective files under each file. This would allow me to more easily convert to microservices if the need by and uses separation of concerns. However I was looking at an [example](https://eltonminetto.net/en/post/2020-07-06-clean-architecture-2years-later/) of implementing this in Go and they structured their file system like the following:

```
| --drivers
|  --/  users
|  --/  posts
| --entities
|  --/  users
|  --/  posts
| --usescases
|  --/  users
|  --/  posts 
| --controllers
|  --/  users
|  --/  posts
```

In this [discussion](https://github.com/eminetto/clean-architecture-go-v2/issues/3) the creator claims that the first file structure is not idiomatic Go. I'm relatively new to Go but not Clean Code and wondering if this is really not good Go code? Should I be using the second file structure, even though it will make converting to microservices rather difficult and it doesn't really follow the separation of concerns principle? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your file structure should have a significant effect on your architecture. You can separate concerns perfectly well no matter where you files are placed on disk, and you can convert to microservices no matter where your files are placed on disk.

Comment: @PhilipKendall In theory yes, but because Go heavily emphasizes packages I'm not sure if this correct as each folder is a package. Packages influence the scope of different structs and functions. I'm asking for a Go idiomatic Clean Code architecture, not just a normal Clean architecture.

Comment: File and folder structure is largely a matter of taste.  Architectures are generally unaffected by it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Isn't the file structure a big aspect of the architecture itself ? In "The principles of clean architecture", Uncle Bob states "this is a rails app because of the file structure [...] why does the file structure tell me what the framework this application is using, why doesn't it tell me what the application does ?".

Comment: Because there are other things like namespaces, classes and interfaces that dictate the architecture, not where you put your files.  Choose an approach for your folder structure that is either "idiomatic," or that makes it easy to find your files.

Comment: That's interesting. So the same architecture would have its file structure look completely different from one project to another if the framework or language used is different, but the architecture would remain unchanged, is that the point ?

Comment: @Steve: I think the point is that the folder structure doesn't inform the architecture, except in the sense that (if you choose to do so), you pick a folder structure that tracks with the architectural structure for convenience reasons.

Comment: The reason the second structure is "better" Go is that it allows for common code to be in one place in one package. E.G.. both the user and posts entities may have common code to handle errors, date formatting database connections etc.. In the first structure this would require repeating the code or another set of "common" folders.

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatic means ["natural and correct"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idiomatic). The file structure of an application might **look** or **feel** natural, correct, or the opposite. But one cannot state only one file structure for a whole language is idiomatic. Yes, you'll have to adapt your implementations, but that is another problem.

> Should I be using the second file structure, even though it will make converting to microservices rather difficult and it doesn't really follow the separation of concerns principle?

The idea of microservices where each project can use its own set of programming language, persistence and cache systems, and the idea to use a file structure that screams "Go" as the main architecture feel illogical to me.

All in all, this question is quite subjective. In the discussion you linked, there are ways to circumvent the importing issues you might run into. So, use the file structure you prefer to work with.

Comment: Quick question on your paragraph: "The idea of microservices... illogical to me". When I say idiomatic I'm not looking for something that screams Go, I'm just looking for a solution that will not go against the flow of Go, which is a highly opinionated language. Thanks for your reply and I do think that it really doesn't matter.